# how to solve this "System.ListException: Duplicate id in list in Trigger"?

Tags: apex, trigger, list

In Product Object ,one record say "A" Rfleet_C2G ParantProduct field contains some value"DZ-Captur".If the value is same as the name field "DZ-Captur" in another record say "B".then will take that "B"record id and insert the id into the "A" record Parent Product field.

**My problem:**

**Record A:** Rfleet_C2G ParantProduct=DZ-Captur

**Record B:** Name=DZ-Captur

then the B id is inserted in A's Parent Product(lookupfield)
this is working fine.

but,

> > Record A: Rfleet_C2G ParantProduct=DZ-Captur
> >
> > Record B: Name=DZ-Captur
> >
> > Record c: Name=DZ-Captur

In this case i got "System.ListException: Duplicate id in list" error

```
trigger:

trigger Rfleet_ParentProductUpdate_Trigger on product2 (after insert,after update){
  if(trigger.isinsert && trigger.isafter){
      Rfleet_DZBatchProductUpdate_CLS updateParent=new Rfleet_DZBatchProductUpdate_CLS();
      updateParent.getParenetProductValues();
   }
}
```

apex code:

```
public class Rfleet_DZBatchProductUpdate_CLS{
    public String strModel1;
    public String strModelId;
    public String strVersion1;
    public List<product2> lstModelprod=new List<product2>();
    public List<product2> lstVersionprod=new List<product2>();
    public List<product2> lstUpdateParent = new List<product2>();

    public void getParenetProductValues() {
        lstModelprod=new List<product2>();
        lstVersionprod=new List<product2>();
        lstUpdateParent = new List<product2>();

       // lstModelprod=[SELECT Id,name FROM Product2 where Rfleet_C2G_version_code__c =null and Country_code__c='DZ'];

        lstModelprod=[SELECT Id,name FROM Product2 where Rfleet_C2G_version_code__c =null];
        system.debug('lstModelprod>>>>>'+lstModelprod);

       // set<String> setModelNames = new set<String>();

       list<String> setModelNames = new list<String>();

        for(product2 strModel:lstModelprod) {
            setModelNames.add(strModel.name);
        }
        map<String, List<Product2>> mapModelNameTolstProduct2 = new map<String, List<Product2>>(); 
        for(Product2 objProduct2: [SELECT Id, Rfleet_C2GParentProduct__c, 
        Rfleet_C2G_version_code__c,Parent_Product__c 
        FROM Product2 WHERE Rfleet_C2GParentProduct__c IN:setModelNames ])
        //and Country_code__c='DZ' ]) 
        { 
            if(mapModelNameTolstProduct2.containsKey(objProduct2.Rfleet_C2GParentProduct__c )) 
            { 
                mapModelNameTolstProduct2.get(objProduct2.Rfleet_C2GParentProduct__c ).add(objProduct2); 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                mapModelNameTolstProduct2.put(objProduct2.Rfleet_C2GParentProduct__c , new List<Product2>{objProduct2}); 
            } 
        }
        for(product2 strModel:lstModelprod) {

            system.debug(strModel.id+':::::'+strModel.name);
            strModel1=strModel.name;
            strModelId=strModel.id;
            system.debug('string Model>>'+strModel1);
            if (mapModelNameTolstProduct2.containsKey(strModel1)){
            system.debug('Inside if>>'+strModel1);
            for(product2 strVersion:mapModelNameTolstProduct2.get(strModel1)) {
                strVersion1=strVersion.id;
                system.debug('success>>');
                system.debug(strVersion1+'::::'+strModel1+'::::'+strModelId);
                Product2 prodt=new Product2();
                prodt.id=strVersion1;
                prodt.Parent_Product__c=strModelId;
                lstUpdateParent.add(prodt);
            }
            }
        }
        update lstUpdateParent;
    }
}
```

how to solve this ? could anyone please help me !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are taking the Collection Type LIST to update the records.

after this line of code `lstUpdateParent.add(prodt);` do the below code.

1) Copy the List `lstUpdateParent` of Products to another SET or MAP (which do not allow the Duplicates).

2) If you copy the List of products to SET, again Copy the SET of Products to another LIST and Update the Newly created list. If you copy the List of products to MAP, Update the MAP directly like

`Update mapUpdateParent.values();`

Hope this helps....

Comment: You have some problems with your advice... 1. You do not avoid a `NullPointerException` by calling `someList.size()`, if it's null you still get the error. 2. There is no reason to check a the size before performing DML. If your list is empty, it will not consume any limits.

Comment: I second Adrian, but would also advise using ! collection.isEmtpy() purely for readability reasons.

Comment: If you are collecting Map of keys(parentid, list<children>), you shouldn't have duplicates. There is high probability that data in Map is corrupted. Using Map later for insert doesn't solve issue, you will have mess in your DB.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't disagree with @Subhash that map will help us to avoid exception.
But actual problem is that **function attempts to save same record few times**.

Statement:

```
for(Product2 objProduct2: [SELECT Id, Rfleet_C2GParentProduct__c, ...
    FROM Product2 WHERE Rfleet_C2GParentProduct__c IN:setModelNames ])
```

Returns all child records for parents setModelNames
e.g. our Parents are `A,B` : we'll have `a1,a2,b1,b2`

Later we have:

```
 map<String, List<Product2>> mapModelNameTolstProduct2 = new map...
```

Gives us map: `A=>{a1,a2}, B=>{b1,b2}`

But in the last `for statement` we are iterating throught list of children:

```
for(product2 strModel:lstModelprod) {
    if (mapModelNameTolstProduct2.containsKey(strModel1)){
        for(product2 strVersion:mapModelNameTolstProduct2.get(strModel1)) {
```

For child a1, we will add a1 and a2, for a2, a1 and a2 etc.

```
{a1,a2,a1,a2,b1,b2,b3,b1,b2, ....}
```

That causes an exception. Change:

```
for(product2 strModel:lstModelprod) {
//...
    for(product2 strVersion:mapModelNameTolstProduct2.get(strModel1)) {
```

To:

```
for(product2 strVersion:mapModelNameTolstProduct2.keyset()){
    //...
    for(product2 mapModelNameTolstProduct2.get(strVersion)) {
```

If you still have exception, possible problem that you are using product2.name as a key
In this case mapModelNameTolstProduct2 will has `map A=>{a1,a2,b1,b2}, A=>{}`

Last `for` for first iteration returns:

```
{a1,a2,b1,b2}
```

And for parent 2nd A it will add same children:

```
{a1,a2,b1,b2,a1,a2,b1,b2}
```

Which throw us exception again

If my assumption is correct, you should find a way to use **unique keys**
e.g. use Id as a key or create unique extId text field

Comment: Rfleet_C2GParentProduct__c value is updated while running the batch.In the batch icant store the id because i dont get the record.Thatsy i updated it in text field.And written atrigger

Comment: But product names are not unique. You should create custId which is unique. And then store in Rfleet_C2GParentProduct__c this unique name.